How do I create a binary dataset in R with several constraints on the proportion of 1's in R
I'm looking at getting a synthetic dataset of eligibility for two treatments, A and B, with constraints. The constraints are 60% 1's for A, 80% 1's for B, 25% 1's for both, and 0% 0's for both. I've not really made any progress as I've only got the following for the columns individually, nothing yet for the joint constraints.
Any help would be really appreciated
# Define the size of the dataset
n <- 1000  # Number of observations

# Generate treatment A
treatment_A <- rep(0, n)
treatment_A[1:(0.6*n)] <- 1

# Generate treatment B
treatment_B <- rep(0, n)
treatment_B[1:(0.8*n)] <- 1 

Example of desired output with n=10
dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),
                  B=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))

Which has 60% A, 70% B, 30% A and B, and 0% not A and B. Not exactly right, but close.

The answer to the question's title is using sample, e.g. sample(0:1, size=10, prob=c(.7, .3), replace=T) with 70% 0s. I don't get the other requirements. Maybe showing a minimal desired output (around size 10) would help.

I've added an example of what I mean.

Can you explain what you really want to do?    A dataset with any exact distribution is not of much interest in the world of statistics and analysis.

There are 4 kinds of AB values:  00, 01, 10, and 11.  Let a, b, c, and d be the counts of each type respectively.
Then your constraints are a+b+c+d = n, c+d = 0.6*n, b+d = 0.8*n, d = 0.25*n, a = 0.  There are no solutions to these equations (unless n=0), so it's impossible to achieve what you are trying to do exactly.  There are lots of approximate solutions; to choose one, you need to decide how to penalize constraint violations.
Let's say the a=0 and a+b+c+d=n constraints have to be met exactly, but the other ones are allowed to vary, and a least squares solution is what you want.  Then the remaining equations are c+d=0.6*n, n-c-d+d = 0.8n (i.e. c = 0.2n), d = 0.25n.
You can get least squares solutions and create the design with code like this:
n <- 1000
A <- structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), dim = 3:2, dimnames = list(NULL, 
                                                                c("c", "d")))
A
#>      c d
#> [1,] 1 1
#> [2,] 1 0
#> [3,] 0 1

x <- n * c(0.60, 0.20,  0.25)
cd <- lsfit(A, x, intercept = FALSE)$coefficients
counts <- c(a = 0, b = n - sum(cd), cd)
counts
#>   a   b   c   d 
#>   0 450 250 300


pairs <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 1, 1), B = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

set.seed(123)
design <- pairs[sample(rep.int(1:4, times = counts)), ]
row.names(design) <- NULL

table(design)
#>    B
#> A     0   1
#>   0   0 450
#>   1 250 300

head(design)
#>   A B
#> 1 0 1
#> 2 1 0
#> 3 0 1
#> 4 1 0
#> 5 0 1
#> 6 1 1

Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.1.0
